# Manipulate strings on MySQL database

Tags: mysql, string, manipulate

I have these strings : `X322-1-381128` and `X322-1-383128`

I need manipulate these strings for get output :

`X322138128` and `X322138328`

I have tried withous success this solution, because the output is only : `X322138128`

Please can you help me ?

```
mysql> SELECT
    'X322-1-381128' string,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX('X322-1-381128', '-', 1) a,
    SUBSTRING('X322-1-381128', 6, 1) b,
    SUBSTRING('X322-1-381128', 8, 2) c,
    SUBSTRING('X322-1-381128' ,- 3) d,
    CONCAT(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX('X322-1-381128', '-', 1),
        SUBSTRING('X322-1-381128', 6, 1),
        SUBSTRING('X322-1-381128', 8, 2),
        SUBSTRING('X322-1-381128' ,- 3)
    ) output,
    'X322-1-383128' string,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX('X322-1-381128', '-', 1) a,
    SUBSTRING('X322-1-381128', 6, 1) b,
    SUBSTRING('X322-1-381128', 8, 2) c,
    SUBSTRING('X322-1-381128' ,- 3) d,
    CONCAT(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX('X322-1-383128', '-', 1),
        SUBSTRING('X322-1-383128', 6, 1),
        SUBSTRING('X322-1-383128', 8, 2),
        SUBSTRING('X322-1-383128' ,- 3)
    ) output;
+---------------+------+---+----+-----+------------+---------------+------+---+----+-----+------------+
| string        | a    | b | c  | d   | output     | string        | a    | b | c  | d   | output     |
+---------------+------+---+----+-----+------------+---------------+------+---+----+-----+------------+
| X322-1-381128 | X322 | 1 | 38 | 128 | X322138128 | X322-1-383128 | X322 | 1 | 38 | 128 | X322138128 |
+---------------+------+---+----+-----+------------+---------------+------+---+----+-----+------------+
1 row in set
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your last `SUBSTRING` is wrong. You want to remove all `-` and the third last number:

```
SELECT
  'X322-1-381128' string,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX('X322-1-381128', '-', 1) a,
  SUBSTRING('X322-1-381128', 6, 1) b,
  SUBSTRING('X322-1-381128', 8, 2) c,
  CONCAT(SUBSTRING('X322-1-381128' ,-4,1), SUBSTRING('X322-1-381128' ,-2)) d,
  CONCAT(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX('X322-1-381128', '-', 1),
    SUBSTRING('X322-1-381128', 6, 1),
    SUBSTRING('X322-1-381128', 8, 2),
    SUBSTRING('X322-1-381128' ,- 3)
  ) output,

  'X322-1-383128' string,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX('X322-1-383128', '-', 1) a,
  SUBSTRING('X322-1-383128', 6, 1) b,
  SUBSTRING('X322-1-383128', 8, 2) c,
  CONCAT(SUBSTRING('X322-1-383128' ,-4,1), SUBSTRING('X322-1-383128' ,-2)) d,
  CONCAT(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX('X322-1-383128', '-', 1),
    SUBSTRING('X322-1-383128', 6, 1),
    SUBSTRING('X322-1-383128', 8, 2),
    SUBSTRING('X322-1-383128' ,-4,1),
    SUBSTRING('X322-1-383128' ,-2)
  ) output;
```

Since your string manipulation is very static you can also use the following much simpler solution:

```
SELECT 'X322-1-381128' string,
  CONCAT(LEFT(REPLACE('X322-1-381128', '-', ''), 8), RIGHT(REPLACE('X322-1-381128', '-', ''), 2))
UNION ALL
SELECT 'X322-1-383128' string,
  CONCAT(LEFT(REPLACE('X322-1-383128', '-', ''), 8), RIGHT(REPLACE('X322-1-383128', '-', ''), 2))
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2244d953515f8e0bfb36064144580479)

Answer (score 1):

use
replace('X322-1-381128','-')

Comment: select replace('X322-1-381128','-','')

Comment: Thanks for reply, but the output must contain 10 characters, instead the input is for 11 characters, only the replace is not sufficient